# Passing Handlers to UICollectionView Cells in Swift

Tags: swift, events, uicollectionview, cell, handler

I'm working on an app in Swift for fun and have found I need to pass at least 2 separate event handlers (closures?) to a cell within a UICollectionView. This is making for a congested constructor and I'm wondering if there's an iOS best practice for achieving this. For example, I have the follownig cell:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var onPictureTap: (() -> ())? = nil
    var onButtonTap: (() -> ())? = nil

    init(onPictureTap: @escaping () -> (), onButtonTap: @escaping () -> (), ) {
        //set properties to args
    }

    @objc func didTouchInsidePicture() {
        if let onPictureTap = self.onPictureTap {
            onPictureTap()
        }
    }

    @objc func didTouchInsideReplyButton() {
        if let onButtonTap = self.onButtonTap {
            onButtonTap()
        }
    }
}
```

This worked well, but I've found I must add another one of these, this time supporting a parameter, and was hoping someone could demonstrate the correct, Swifty/iOS-y way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the cell only contain a picture and tapping anywhere on the cell should have the same effect ?  If so you could use didSelectItem at indexPath function which is part of `UICollectionVoewDelegate`

Comment: The cell contains multiple views, each with their own behaviors and I unfortunately can't account for them all in the didSelectItem method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found most projects will set these after instantiation. e.g.

```
let cell = Cell()
cell.onPictureTap = ...
```

Works well and has no adverse effects (that I can spot!)